# Why does my webm not work in Unity but others do?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, video, ffmpeg

Ok Im just trying to play a transparent video in Unity and Im following http://mikebrinkerink.com/2018/04/05/preparing-a-video-with-alpha-channel-for-unity/ and other tutorials.

Ive tried exporting as ProRes 444 with alpha and as Webm VP8, and using terminal ffmpeg commands. Yet when I drop the video into Unity it loads indefinitely and I have to force quit.

My file is this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RhOvYfeaK1rEaKdlTNcJB9EBpz4xxjvw/view?usp=sharing

And this one that I downloaded works fine: https://simpl.info/videoalpha/video/dancer1.webm

Whats the difference/how can I get mine to work?

Log:

```
ffmpeg -i my_clip_with_alpha.avi -vcodec vp8 -acodec libvorbis -pix_fmt yuva420p -metadata:s:v:0 alpha_mode=”1″ -auto-alt-ref 0 my_vp8_clip_with_alpha.webm​
```

as the command (with my clip's name)

Then

```
built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-libaom --enable-libsoxr
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/skylarthomas/Desktop/INSTRUCTIONS1_00000.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2019-03-27T00:19:30.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:17.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 40959 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (ap4h / 0x68347061), yuva444p10le(tv, bt709, progressive), 2215x1773, 40467 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 2215:1773, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-03-27T00:19:30.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 4444
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-03-27T00:19:30.000000Z
      handler_name    : Time Code Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (prores (native) -> vp8 (libvpx))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libvpx @ 0x7fe11701d600] v1.8.0
Output #0, webm, to 'my_vp8_clip_with_alpha.webm':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8 (libvpx), yuva420p, 2215x1773 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2215:1773], q=-1--1, 200 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 1k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-03-27T00:19:30.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
      alpha_mode      : ”1″
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libvpx
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=    2 fps=2.0 q=0.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:00.03 bitrate= 200.7kbits/sframe=    6 fps=3.7 q=0.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:00.16 bitrate=  40.6kbits/sframe=   10 fps=4.5 q=0.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:00.30 bitrate=  22.7kbits/s speedframe=   35 fps=2.9 q=0.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:01.13 bitrate=   6.0kbits/s speed=0.0934x
```

Comment: Show your ffmpeg command that made the webm and the complete log.

Comment: @llogan see my edit

Comment: Don't use so-called *smart quotes*. Change `alpha_mode=”1″` to `alpha_mode="1"` (but I'm not familiar with that metadata and didn't look it up). If that doesn't work do a test run with `-vf scale=640:-1` to see if Unity doesn't like the original output size.